# Perspective with fixed aspect ratio (1:1) in OpenGL and Qt5 (QGLWidget)

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5, qglwidget

I'm trying to render a cube into a QGLWidgetput inside a QSplitter. I'd like it to have a 1:1 ratio so it is a cube and keeps that ratio regardless of window dimensions. I haven't been able to get this to work, though. No matter what I do, the cube stretches with the window.

I have two additional problems with how the code works.

- `matrix.setToIdentity()` resets everything except projection and translation which happen at the end of `initializeGL()`, and so when I invoke it in `resizeGL()`, the projection combines with the previous one, even if I set the matrix to identity before that.
- The argument `aspect ratio` of `matrix.perspective()` seems to be doing nothing. I've tried several values with no effect.
- For some reason, the projection is orthographic, not perspective.
- The matrix is still an identity after `perspective()`, but only if I call `setToIdentity()` and `perspective()` in `resizeGL` in that order.
- Matrix operations in `initializeGL()` and `resizeGL()` get different treatment. If I don't call `translate()` and `perspective()` in `initializeGL()`, the cube will not appear even if I do it later in `resizeGL()`.

Can anyone explain this to me? I thought that `QMatrix4x4` class was here to hold the matrices to 3D transformations so I don't have to implement them myself.

I've looked at some tutorials, but either they use some kind of matrices in a similar way or they seem to use deprecated OpenGL functions. Tried casting width and height to floats and using separate matrices for transformations.

**How do I make the 1:1 ratio work?**

A relevant piece of my code:

```
void ModelView::initializeGL()
{
    m_program = new QGLShaderProgram(this);
    m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader::Vertex, vertexShaderSource);
    m_program->addShaderFromSourceCode(QGLShader::Fragment, fragmentShaderSource);
    m_program->link();

    GLuint shader_id = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shader_id, 1, vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader_id);
    ShaderIds[2] = shader_id;

    shader_id = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shader_id, 1, fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader_id);
    ShaderIds[1] = shader_id;

    glAttachShader(ShaderIds[0], ShaderIds[1]);
    glAttachShader(ShaderIds[0], ShaderIds[2]);

    glLinkProgram(ShaderIds[0]);*/

    matrix.setToIdentity(); //--------------------------------------

    float aspect = (((float)width())/((float)height()));

    matrix.perspective(60, aspect, 0.1, 100.0);
    matrix.translate(0, 0, -2);
}

void ModelView::paintGL()
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    glClearColor(.5f, .5f, .5f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, width(), height());

    m_program->bind();

    m_posAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("posAttr");
    m_colAttr = m_program->attributeLocation("colAttr");
    m_matrixUniform = m_program->uniformLocation("matrix");
    m_program->setUniformValue(m_matrixUniform, matrix); //-----------------

    glGenBuffers(1, &BufferId);
    glGenBuffers(1, &IndexBufferId);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferId);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IndexBufferId);

    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferSize, Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(m_posAttr, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VertexSize, 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(m_colAttr, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, VertexSize, (GLvoid *)RgbOffset);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    m_program->release();

}

void ModelView::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    matrix.setToIdentity();  //------------------------------------

    matrix.translate(0, 0, -2);
    matrix.perspective(60, ((float)w)/((float)h), 0.1, 100.0);

    updateGL();
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting a uniform value before getting the uniform location?

Comment: Er, I took some of the code from the only tutorial that worked on my old hardware. Should it be the other way around, then?

Comment: Yes.  Think about it: What is the value of `m_matrixUniform` before you call `m_matrixUniform = m_program->uniformLocation("matrix")`?

Comment: Undefined, I'd say. I had a feeling there was something fishy about that.

Comment: Yep.  Though in this particular case if you zero-initialize `m_matrixUniform` in your constructor it probably won't be a problem since the first uniform location is *usually* zero.

Comment: In `resizeGL()` what happens when you swap the order of the `translate()` and `perspective()` calls?

Comment: Nothing changes. The `translate()` can't be there at all, otherwise the cube disappears. And `perspective()` needs to have its first argument `angle` set to zero. I thought setting a matrix to identity resetted everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found what was wrong.

First, matrix operations shouldn't be in `initializeGL()`. Not exactly sure why. The correct (and reasonable, come to think of it) place is in `resizeGL()`, as it gets called somewhere about the first frame render.

Second, matrix multiplications have their defined order, which goes like perspective > translate > rotate. Otherwise it screws up.

So the correct (or at least working) code in `resizeGL()` goes like this:

```
glViewport(startX, startY, width, height);    //resize the viewport
matrix.setToIdentity();             //reset the uniform value (matrix)
perspectiveMatrix.setToIdentity();   //reset the projection matrix
                                       //set new projection (aspect ratio)
perspectiveMatrix.perspective(angle, (float)width/(float)height, nearPlane, farPlane);

matrix *= perspectiveMatrix;    //apply transformations
matrix *= translationMatrix;
matrix *= rotationMatrix;

updateGL();                  //re-render
```